# testRigor - Is there any Support for Integration with AWS CodeBuild

Tags: aws-codebuild, testrigor

I could see some bash commands in the  CI/CD section of the tool. But is there any case study or proven case where the cases would be integrated with AWS Codebuild please ? Also is it Supported with testRigor at the moment ? If Yes, can you explain how ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AWS CodeBuild is supported by testRigor out of the box.
The way it works is you copy the script from CI/CD section and paste it as a bash script which is triggered in CodeBuild. Works out of the box.
I know it is not exactly the same but here is a video showing how to use it with GitHub Actions which is hopefully will clarify some things: https://youtu.be/f8QFFHBywto